# How can I push an element into an array reference held as a hash value?

Tags: perl

```
%data = (
    'digits' => [1, 2, 3],
    'letters' => ['a', 'b', 'c']
);
```

How can I `push` `'4'` into `$data{'digits'}`?

I am new to Perl. Those `$`, `@`, `%` symbols look weird to me; I come from a PHP background.

Comment: See [perldoc perldata](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldata.html) and [perldoc perldsc](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldsc.html) for information on perl data structures.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
push @{ $data{'digits'} }, 4;
```

$data{'digits'} returns an array-reference. Put @{} around it to "dereference it". In the same way, %{} will dereference a hash reference, and ${} a scalar reference.

If you need to put something into a hash reference, i.e.

```
$hashref = { "foo" => "bar" }
```

You can use either:

```
${ $hashref }{ "foo2" } = "bar2"
```

or the arrow-notation:

```
$hashref->{"foo2"} = "bar2"
```

In a certain way, think of a reference as the same thing as the name of the variable:

```
push @{ $arrayref   }, 4
push @{ "arrayname" }, 4
push    @arrayname   , 4
```

In fact, that's what "soft references" are. If you don't have all the strictnesses turned on, you can literally:

```
# perl -de 0
  DB<1> @a=(1,2,3)
  DB<2> $name="a"
  DB<3> push @{$name}, 4
  DB<4> p @a
1234
```

Comment: A non-hard reference is a symbolic reference.

Answer (score 3):

```
push @{data{'digits'}}, 4;
```

The @{} makes an array from a reference (`data{'digits'}` returns an array reference.)  Then we use the array we got to push the value 4 onto the array in the hash.

This [link](http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/perl/prog3/ch09_02.htm) helps explain it a little bit.

I use this [link](http://www.cs.mcgill.ca/~abatko/computers/programming/perl/howto/hash/) for any questions about hashes in Perl.

Answer (score 2):

For an exotic but very pleasing on the eye option take a look at the [`autobox::Core`](http://search.cpan.org/dist/autobox-Core/) CPAN module.

```
use autobox::Core;

my %data = (
    digits  => [1, 2, 3],
    letters => ['a', 'b', 'c'],
);

$data{digits}->push(4);

$data{digits}->say;   # => 1 2 3 4
```

Answer (score 1):

```
push @{ $data{digits} }, 4;
```

The official Perl documentation website has a good tutorial on data structures: [perldsc](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldsc.html), particularly the [Hashes-of-Arrays](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldsc.html#HASHES-OF-ARRAYS) section.

$, @ and % are known as sigils.