# Perl: How to push elements in array as hash value using if exists statement

Tags: arrays, perl, hash, reference

I'm working with markers having multiple chromosome locations. For each marker, I'd like to get all the chromosome locations such as:

```
 marker_1 1A, 3B, 5D; marker_2 2D, 2A
```

I'm coming from Ruby world and I've been scratching my head with reference/dereference of array and hash.I'm getting more and more confused.
Could you please help me out? Thank you in advance for your time and your helpful assistance.

My code below works. However, instead of concatenating $location to an existing 'string' location, I'd like to push $location in an array. I'm not sure how to do that.

```
my %loc_info;

while(<IN>){
    my @info = split(/\s+/);
    my $marker = $info[1];
    my $location = $info[2];

    if (exists $loc_info{$marker}){
        $loc_info{$marker} .= ",$location";## help for pushing in array
    }else{
        $loc_info{$marker} = $location; ##
    }
}#while

     foreach (sort keys %loc_info){
         print "$_\t $loc_info{$_}\n";
      }
```

Comment: Just use `push @{ $loc_info{$marker} }, $location;` and you don't need prior test with `exists`.

Comment: Please post that as an answer. (I'm sorry, I can't address my comment as I can't type your name and I'm using the tablet app which provides neither auto-complete nor copy.)

Comment: @Kpangee: Whenever you use `split /\s+/` you almost certainly want `split ' '` (with exactly one space) or just `split` which is identical

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I push an element into an array reference held as a hash value?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3221380/how-can-i-push-an-element-into-an-array-reference-held-as-a-hash-value)

Comment: See also: [autovivification](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlglossary.html#autovivification) for why you can use nonexistent data structures as if they already existed

Answer (score 4):

As has been mentioned, Perl's *autovivication* will allow you to `push` to a non-existent hash element. An anonymous array will be created for you

I would write this

```
while ( <IN> ) {
    my @info = split;
    my ($marker, $location) = @info[1,2];
    push @{ $loc_info{$marker} }, $location;
}

for my $mk ( sort keys %loc_info ) {
    my $locs = $loc_info{$mk};
    print $mk, "\t", join('; ', @$locs), "\n";
}
```

Comment: Hi Folks,thank you so much for sharing your knowledge with me. I really appreciate your help.